# Which Rails app server is request being requested from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I have a rails app with 3 different app servers.  If I wanted to display the server that the request was served from on the rails view ow would I do that?

More specifically my issue has to to with Delayed jobs.  I have workers on each app server.  I have an intermittent bug when the DJ creates an exception and reports the exception to rollbar.  I'd like to know what server the intermittent bug is being generated from (without going to the log files).

Is there a command that will tell me which app server the Delayed Job process was executed on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways is to export environment variables that help you uniquely identify the server and then simply read that variable.  For example:

```
export THIS_SERVER='batman'

04:42:09:website >> rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.0.0-p451 :001 > ENV["THIS_SERVER"]
=> "batman"
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something along those lines.  The issue is if I had 50 app servers (thank god I don't) I'd have to set `THIS_SERVER` 50 times...   I did find out `ip = \`hostname\``

Comment: If you need a scalable solution, then definitely tie into one of the Linux utilities such as uname, hostname, or even ifconfig.  There are lots of ways to get the info you need.  Another alternative is to put the info into your capistrano deploy scripts so the variables get set that way instead of having to log into each server to set it up.  At the end of the day, pick something that gets the job done with the appropriate level of effort to accomplish your task.